# Fold a List in Half

Tags: code-golf, array

We are going to fold a list of integers.  The procedure to do so is as follows,  If the list is of even length, make a list of half of its length where the nth item of the new list is the sum of the nth item of the old list and the nth-to-last item of the old list.  For example if we had the list

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
```

We would fold it like so

```
 [8 7 6 5]
+[1 2 3 4]
__________
 [9 9 9 9]
```

If the list is of *odd* length, to fold it we first remove the middle item, fold it as if it were even and the append the middle item to the result.

For example if we had the list

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

We would fold it like so

```
 [7 6 5]
+[1 2 3]
__________
 [8 8 8]
++     [4]
__________
 [8 8 8 4]
```

### Task

Write a program or function that takes a list of integers as input and outputs that list folded.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) question so answers will be scored in bytes, with fewer bytes being better.

### Sample implementation

Here's an implementation in Haskell that defines a function `f` that performs a fold.

```hs
f(a:b@(_:_))=a+last b:f(init b)
f x=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00j0SrJQSPeKl5T0zZROyexuEQhySpNIzMvE8jQ5EpTqLCt@J@bmJlnW1CUmVeikhZtqGOkY6xjomOqYxb7HwA)

Comment: When you say integers, does this include zero or negative integers?

Comment: @Neil Yes it does.

Comment: Are we supposed to sort the list, or just take what we're given? Also is any type of collection allowed, or just a list (for languages with multiple types of collections)?

Comment: @GrzegorzPuławski You should not sort the list.  Any ordered collection is allowed, e.g. vector or array.

Comment: Now make it recursive and see how many times you can fold a list in half before you overflow.

Comment: @DavidStarkey Most reasonable lists will not overflow with a reasonable amount of memory.  Folding doesn't actually increase the sum so lists will converge to a singleton of the sum of the original list.

Comment: @WheatWizard That's what I meant, keep folding until one of the items in the list overflows.  Sure it needs larger lists than your examples, but that's kinda the point.

Comment: @WheatWizard I don't know about that, I've heard it's impossible to fold any list in half more than 7 times.

Comment: I would find it easier to visualize and follow if the odd length example just kept the [4] as a fourth column, in between the two rows.

Answer (score 11):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 46 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:l[1:]and[l[0]+l[-1]]+f(l[1:-1])or l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYxBCoNAEATPySv6qNgBV5MYF/KSYQ4rskSYrCJe8vpVH5BLU1RBL7/tM6cm5/i28B3GAPMmzmtIo5jUWpncnGoVi1MfWM4rLMdzMSWIIxqiJe7Eg3gSHfFS/itEr/56WdYpbThey7wD)

Same length:

```python
f=lambda l:l[1:]and[l.pop(0)+l.pop()]+f(l)or l
```

A much shorter solution works for even-length lists (30 bytes)

```python
lambda l:[x+l.pop()for x in l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcnLCkBAGAbQNU/xLcmXcr@UJ2EWpIn6zUyy4OlHHsDu1HHPtVmTez1MXuZjWWdIP96JpM66KNb2xI3dQJT/LJ/HjMiJgiiJiqiJhmgV/4boVB8G7tzNBR1J7F8)

I'm still trying to find a short way to  correct it for odd length.

Comment: Oh, I got terribly outgolfed ÷_÷

Comment: The "middle ground" solution `f=lambda l:l[1:]and[l[0]+l.pop()]+f(l[1:])or l` is also the same length...

Answer (score 10):

## [Emojicode](http://www.emojicode.org/), 203 bytes

```
i⏩0➗2➕i➖➕1i1012➗210
```

This was the most painful Emojicode answer to code for me. The unnecessary length :/

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S83Nz8pMzk9J/f//w/wJ3R/m964A4nYge9qH@VMWQdhTmjIf9a80eDRvOlB8ChBPNYJIzGgASi58NG8qkLsLyNwElNsLks/8MH9WE7rgo3nTYPqBWgzBagwNgKo6gbgLaNpsQ6DQOqx2YJqF7BYkc8AY6Jf@RgWQfgUuBQWQR0CcFQqGCkYKxgomCqYKZgrmIKE2LrByAA)

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

#### Code

```
2ä`R+
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f6PCShCDt//@jDXUUjHQUjHUUTHQUTHUUzHQUzGMB)

#### Explanation

```
2ä        # Split the list into two pieces
  `       # Flatten the stack
   R      # Reverse the second element from the list
    +     # Vectorized addition
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>21</s> <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
l
íUj°V/2V w)mx
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=CmwK7VVqsFYvMlYgdylteA==&input=WzEgMiAzIDQgNSA2IDdd)

<s>Completely awful</s> Slightly less awful thanks to [@Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613). BRB after I implement more built-ins and fix some bugs...

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
œs2U2¦S
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5GKjUKNDy4L///8fbaijYKSjYKyjYKKjYKqjYKajYK6jYBELAA)

-2 thanks to [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)...and me realizing before.

Comment: ETH was right, [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5GKjUKNDy4L///8fbaijYKSjYKyjYKKjYKqjYKajYB4LAA)

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks, although I had already figured out after I shut my computer down.

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia/blob/master/codepage.md)

```
e2÷ev+†
```

#### Explanation

```
e        Eval the input (push the list).
 2÷      Split it in half. The first half will be longer for an odd length.
   e     Dump the two halves on the stack.
    v    Reverse the second.
     +†  Element-wise addition. If the first half has an extra element, it is simply appended.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>55</s> 41 bytes

```c
f(_,l)int*_;{for(;l--;*_+++=l?_[l--]:0);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY7dCoJAFITvfYppQdh1j5D2o7RIDyIhYRjClqLWjfjsdlbpoovuZphv5pwyvJflPFeyIKvq5xAUZqyaThobhiYotNaZPRc5u8tpq8w0v5v6hrZj9Np10jXAgsAKVmH0uA1p4PpqBSsp/JvfC0LAqNYEAaE3VhmvfQ29FILV5D2u9VO6BTc1RPklGyNCTNgR9oQD4UhICOlkViT@g3BeySGi1B34fsp@r5YgpuQniJdgmj8)

Overwrites the first \$\left\lfloor\frac{l}{2}\right\rfloor\$ entries of the input array.

#### [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 46 bytes

```c
f(_,l)int*_;{_=l>1?*_+=_[l-1],1+f(_+1,l-2):l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc7LCsIwEAXQfb/iGhCSZrJIfLQYqh@iEqRSKcQqbXVT@u01VUEE3V1mzjxydcrzYSi4Iy/Kqo2d7Vzm13oTO5m5rVd6T1qGvtTklRErb/vhfimPuNbBH@qaj2MIgRASvEAXFZca3MIrZcULFpxNj9OGEeJApSQwMDnxwkbXW9twxkLqo/OhrPi4YVzV6u0@6zTBEGaEOWFBWBISQtrbFzF/SOh/7u4qRgVvNaVCvOvj46EwFz@coeTbmafrhwc)

Additionally returns the length \$\left\lceil\frac{l}{2}\right\rceil\$ of the output.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
I÷Ṙ+
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJJw7fhuZgrIiwiIiwiWzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDYsIDddIl0=)

```
I    # Halve the list
 ÷   # Push each half
  Ṙ  # Reverse the second half
   + # Add them together (vectorising)
```

Comment: [5 bytes by taking the input as a string of characters with corresponding ascii values](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C2%BDC%C3%B7%E1%B9%98%2B&inputs=%01%02%03%04%05%06%07%0A&header=&footer=)

Comment: [4 bytes because @lyxal's being a sussy baka and not using flags](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=Ṫ&code=%C2%BDC%C3%B7%E1%B9%98&inputs=%01%02%03%04%05%06%07%0A&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
YCHa;@y+Ry@1
```

-2 Thanks to [DLosc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/16766/dlosc)!

How?

```
YCHa;@y+Ry@1  : One arg; list
   a          : First input
 CH           : Chop iterable into 2 pieces of roughly equal length
Y             : Yank value
         y    : The two halves
          @1  : Get item/slice at index 1; The second half
        R     : Reverse
       +      : Add with
      y       : The two halves
     @        : Get item at index 0; The first half
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJZQ0hhO0B5K1J5QDEiLCIiLCIiLCInWzE7MjszOzQ7NTs2OzddJyAteCJd)

Comment: @DLosc that was so obvious I don't know how I missed it lol, thanks for the spot!

Comment: @DLosc I see what you mean, it made sense when I wrote it, should be fixed now! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$23\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 18.932 bytes

```
J+t_HLxxt_HLx$xs_HLxtHL
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJKK3RfSEx4eHRfSEx4JHhzX0hMeHRITCIsIlsxLDIsMyw0LDUsNiw3XSJd)

\$-26\log_{256}(96)\approx21.401\$ thanks to [Seggan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107299/seggan)

First time using Fig. Any golfing tips are welcome.

#### Explanation (outdated):

```
fw+[yfy$fy$fyx[yfy$fy$fy$x?h%1HLx[]yfy$fy$fyx]yW1
   [yfy$fy$fyx                                    First Mid
  +                                               Add
              [yfy$fy$fy$x                        Second Mid
fw                                                Concat
                          ?                       If
                           h%1HLx                 List length is odd,
                                 []yfy$fy$fyx     Mid
                                             ]yW1 Else Empty list
```

Comment: the entire if (`?h%1HLx[]yfy$fy$fyx]yW1`) can be replaced with `s_HLxtHL` (take half, drop half; will return empty list if even, middle item if odd). `fw` can be `J`

Comment: [`J+t_HLxxt_HLx$xs_HLxtHL` works](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJKK3RfSEx4eHRfSEx4JHhzX0hMeHRITCIsIlsxLDIsMyw0LDUsNiw3XSJd)

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
2ẆẸr+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWK40e7mp7uGtHkfaS4qTkYqjogvXRhjpGOsY6JjqmOmY65rEQYQA)

```
2ẆẸr+ # implicit input
2Ẇ    # split list in half
  Ẹ   # push both halves to the stack
   r  # reverse top one
    + # vectorized addition
      # implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>81</s> <s>70</s> <s>68</s> 57 bytes

```r
function(l)c((l+rev(l))[1:(w=sum(l|1)/2)],l[w+1][!!w%%1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jRzNZQyNHuyi1DMjUjDa00ii3LS7N1cipMdTUN9KM1cmJLtc2jI1WVCxXVTWM1fyfpmFoZaLJBaJMIZQZhDKHUBaa/wE)

anonymous function; returns the result.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 88 bytes

```
(d=Array[s[[#]]+s[[-#]]&,x=⌊t=Length[s=#]/2⌋];If[IntegerQ@t,d,d~AppendTo~s[[x+1]]])&
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica 57 Bytes

```
(#+Reverse@#)[[;;d-1]]&@Insert[#,0,d=⌈Length@#/2⌉+1]&
```

Inserts a zero at the midpoint, adds the list to its reverse and takes the appropriate length.

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 53 bytes

```javascript
x=>x.splice(0,x.length/2).map(y=>y+x.pop()).concat(x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc3dCoIwGIDhc6/iOwjc6GuV/YLMGzHBsaZNbBu6ZBJd@wrPO37heTsxiVEO2vmNsXcVGx4DLwIbXa@lIjsMrFem9Y9tRtlTODLzYl4H5qwjlDJpjRSeBBrzSQygjXt54FAmAOUeIUM4IBwRTghnhAvCtcI/rUqqPPl5o@0V621LFmx5CuAF1Kt3QwT91JR1VhuS3kxKaR6/)

Another suggestion:

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 43 bytes

```javascript
f=x=>x+x?[x.pop()+(0|x.shift()),...f(x)]:[]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcxLCsIwEADQfU8xC6EJjoN/xZJ6kBhoqI2m1CS0tQTUs0dw7/rBa/Wkh7q3YVw4f21SMiKKMs7jWUYKPjA@Z8t3pOFuzcg4RyIyLHJ1kioVk@7BuvAcQYDMAOQKYY2wQdgi7BD2CAeEo8I/pjJVZLV3g@8a6vyN/TJ66MA0iBKq2cswzT8Vp9Zbx/KLyzkv0hc)

Comment: `(0|x.shift())` => `~~x.shift()`

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 41 bytes

```
f=a=>1/a[1]?[a.shift()+a.pop(),...f(a)]:a
```

```js
f=a=>1/a[1]?[a.shift()+a.pop(),...f(a)]:a

console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7])));
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 12 bytes

```
å@o +Y*(Z<Ul
```

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=5UBvICtZKihaPFVs&inputs=WzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDYsIDdd,WzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDYsIDcsIDhd,WzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDcsOCw5LDEwLDExLDEyLDEzXQ==,WzEsMiwzXQ==,WzUsNCwzLDIsMV0=&flags=LVE=) with the `-Q` flag to view the formatted array.

### Alternate solution, 14 bytes

```
o(½*Ul)c)íU mx
```

[Try it online!](https://codepen.io/justinm53/full/NvKjZr?code=byi9KlVsKWMp7VUgbXg=&inputs=WzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDYsIDdd,WzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDYsIDcsIDhd,WzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDcsOCw5LDEwLDExLDEyLDEzXQ==,WzEsMiwzXQ==,WzUsNCwzLDIsMV0=&flags=LVE=)

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 55 bytes

If the answer must be put to stdout, but output whitespace is flexible, **55 bytes**:

```sh
for ((;++i<=#/2;))<<<$[$@[i]+$@[-i]]
<<<$@[#%2*(1+#/2)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzLCoMwEEX38xWXaEEbQmuq1mIE/0OyEIwYEAXti/58mnTZuxhmzhnuZ5/cbu4Qb3pNdjbYTD9gtoupMaxknv2MnxdgccDMjeuGJKk5t6qJTrJOU6VU3MVtZzX3U1itKaC2iw7ymGTcf6XaPZZQZINiTQijYV2MyyBxQY4CJa6o6O/GjUQGUfm9gCi9OFMuib4)

---

If the output must be stored in an array, **53 bytes**: (We can't use this method in place of the above because of `<<<...[--i]...`. The here-string forces a subshell, so the decremented value of `i` never makes it out.)

```sh
for n ($@[1,#/2])y+=($[$@[--i]+n])
y+=$@[#%2*(1+#/2)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYzLCoMwFET39yuGmILWhjapWksV@h@ShWCKAYmgfdmfT2OXvas5Z4b7mXs/mzvEm169HQwm03YYrDMXdCOZZzvg1wswvmrmb@MEh5hfG7mL9konS1rHvAkshNWp0wkFEzDaqG0s07BJtK@qii/0cOszB4uFgmH1eoy60RkvoXBEhhwFTijpj3EmISHKkHOIIhQHyhTRFw)

If the answer must be output in one line separated by spaces, then append `<<<$y` for a 6 byte penalty.

---

Zsh arrays are indexed from the start starting at `1`, or from the end starting at `-1`. So what happens if you attempt to index at `0`? Well, nothing! We take advantage of that here to only output the middle number based on a parity check:

```sh
$@[#%2*(1+#/2)]
   #      #       # parameter count
       (1+#/2)    # index of the middle element when count is odd
   #%2*(1+#/2)    # multiply by 0 if even, or 1 if odd
$@[           ]   # Index the parameter array
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 35 bytes

```
[ halves reverse 0 pad-longest v+ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY29DgFBFEZ7T/H1YuOf0OhEoxGVKMb62I0xu@69JkT22QeVQndycpJzcrlVkrab1Xo5g/J2Z8ipP8r4MHGKq7Mii/zWigsl0KMWmj1rKYNh3mq90EMfAwwxwhgTTNH8uSbtUDgfPwthpCjRRe2OHV@FM9UQ29inQ7lApsg9naQ3)

### Explanation

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes a sequence from the data stack and leaves a sequence on the data stack. Assuming `{ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 }` is on the data stack when this quotation is called...

| Snippet | Comment | Data stack (top on right) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `halves` | Split a sequence in half | `{ 1 2 3 } { 4 5 6 7 }` |
| `reverse` | Reverse a sequence | `{ 1 2 3 } { 7 6 5 4 }` |
| `0 pad-longest` | Pad the shorter of two sequences with 0s until it's the same length as the longer sequence | `{ 1 2 3 0 } { 7 6 5 4 }` |
| `v+` | Vector addition; element-wise addition between two sequences | `{ 8 8 8 4 }` |

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 115 bytes

```go
func(x[]int)(o[]int){s:=len(x)
for i:=range x[:s/2]{o=append(o,x[i]+x[s-i-1])}
if s%2>0{o=append(o,x[s/2])}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dU5LasMwFNzrFGogIBE5bdz8MKhnyN54IWLJiMZPRpKDwOgW3WVjCj1UblM7zqKBZjW8mTefy3dl-utLI46fopK4FhqQrhtj_XKmaj9D6CwsVvyn9SrZX51q4UhCXmjwlJgJO5fxkwQSKFLGYp1xK2AIC3nmXtOiM1w0jYSSGBZyXSxC7hKdrAoakVbYzdOPt8ef0TWIVvrWQrxXf43Vt4GE4g7JswSccXyb0K1Yyt7Zmm3Ylu3YPiJTlk_UiA52IE9AFBlDKP1DDLaHe_Jv4j_kyN239f2Evw)

#### Generic with custom operator, 136 bytes

```go
func f[T any](x[]T,O func(T,T)T)(o[]T){s:=len(x)
for i:=range x[:s/2]{o=append(o,O(x[i],x[s-i-1]))}
if s%2>0{o=append(o,x[s/2])}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fVHNTgMhGIxXnoJsYgIpVVutNmvWV6iHvW2IYf8qdgsrbO2aDXffwUtj4sVH8E30aQTpxmoaD4TJDN8wMM8vc7l5r1m2YPMCLhkXgC9rqZqjoFw2AXhdNeVw-vFUrkQGyySGTDxS1CY0JjPoSBSTGMcYSUvhTodRVQjUYlBKBXkYKSasb5uE-nhMOxmxui5EjiSZWRNOSZvoIR-OKMYG8BLqw_HVye4xq9tBK6qiWSlhfJ7Pg7fvQC4vwrADLM9hGPlAjKSQiwbb1fkpyAapAcVDIdyhhDplRMbklJyRCTknF2RqgPQWe1QDrpUlK4HKxO4UOSdir8T4r2JN9gvedmL-U3sR6EZpn8UiLuZdcFtUlQwIDNZSVbkD9yueLRxIlVwLB0rZBgbUSt4VWcOl-PUh3sjW1KPOFXRDVF8R2xK6J9LO9qGiSHdyEPkhpLAx5hJuu9h5hdcpcskJ_MlgX7OtbLPx-xc)

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc), <s>62 bytes</s> 60 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to [@ceilingcat](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52904/ceilingcat)

```
i;f(v,l)int*v;{for(i=0;i<l/2;++i)v[i]+=v[l+~i];return~l/-2;}
```

`f` is a function taking vector (`v`) and length (`l`) as arguments. It modifies the vector and returns the new length.

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##VY9hi4MwDIY/N78iDAbtWdEJd18yf4nIOJzdBXp1ONfBxP11r9UxdvkSwvs8CWnSU9PMM5ORXlvFbvjwNJqul1zmxHubFZQkrHzFdVL6yiYPrqlvh2vvHjZLC5oAgoW/3@yk7/ioYAR8VgwsX4aqxhLHT41fGguNu1xjutMYWjERiAVr3Wn4CZi88L3tzOIpzP7NVV4rglVw7e3wkoyMsX5uCYwIL6CMHIc4p9D2bwphfApHEOLcB8rIzfaIG71e4XhFTDDBPP8B)

How it works:

```
i;
f(v,l) int*v; // v is an integer pointer (or array), l is an integer
{
    for (i = 0; i < l / 2; ++i) // iterate through half the indices using i (if l is odd, the middle element won't be included)
        v[i] += v[l + ~i]; // add the value at the i'th index from the back to the i'th index from the front. ~i == -i - 1, so l + ~i == l + -i -1 = l - i - 1 (l - 1 is the first index from the back, and we subtract i for each index beyond the first)
    return ~l / -2; // return half the length rounded up (~l == -l - 1 => ~l / -2 == (-l - 1) / -2 => (l + 1) / 2
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Answer (score 2):

## [Curry (PAKCS)](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/index.html), 34 bytes

```
f(a:b++[c])=a+c:f b
f x@([]?[_])=x
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m706ubSoqDK-IDE7uXjBgqWlJWm6FjeV0jQSrZK0taOTYzVtE7WTrdIUkrjSFCocNKJj7aPjgYIVEJW7chMz8xRsFdIUog11jHSMdUx0THXMdMx1LGIhCmBGAgA)

Based on the sample implementation in Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>69</s> 68 bytes

```julia
!s=(~=length;~s%2>0&&insert!(s,(1+~s)÷2,0);(s+reverse(s))[1:~s÷2])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X7HYVqPONic1L70kw7quWNXIzkBNLTOvOLWoRFGjWEfDULuuWPPwdiMdA01rjWLtotSy1KLiVI1iTc1oQ6u6YqBMrOZ/h8RikAYFxWhDHSMdYx0THVMdMx1zHYtYBVtbhWhLHTCM5cKhDqLKQgcETWL/AwA)

-1 byte thanks to MarcMush: replace `==1` with `>0`

Comment: -1 byte: `>0` instead of `==1`

Answer (score 2):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/), <s>15</s> 12 bytes

```bqn
(⌊≠÷2˙)⊸↑⊢+⌽
```

[Try it online!](https://bqnpad.mechanize.systems/s?bqn=eyJkb2MiOiJpbnB1dCDihpAg4p%2BoMSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNSwgNSwgNiwgNywgOOKfqVxuU29sIOKGkCAo4oyK4omgw7cyy5kp4oq44oaR4oiYKOKKoivijL0pXG5Tb2wgaW5wdXQiLCJwcmV2U2Vzc2lvbnMiOltdLCJjdXJyZW50U2Vzc2lvbiI6eyJjZWxscyI6W10sImNyZWF0ZWRBdCI6MTY3NDI0MDM3ODA1OX0sImN1cnJlbnRDZWxsIjp7ImZyb20iOjAsInRvIjo2NywicmVzdWx0IjpudWxsfX0%3D)

-3 thanks to Marshall Lochbaum

Sum the list and its reverse, then take the first `⌊≠÷2˙` digits. `⌊≠÷2˙` the floor of the length divide 2. Floor is necessary because there is no integer division in BQN. `⊸` is used to bind the output of `⌊≠÷2˙` to the take operator `↑` on the left and also puts the output of `(⊢+⌽)` on the right. Better explanation [here](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/tutorial/combinator.html#before-and-after).

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: Thank you! I only wish my explanation was as concise...

Comment: I don't think this gives the correct output for lists with an odd number of elements.  The output of "1 2 3 4 5 6 7" should be "8 8 8 4", not just "8 8 8"...

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 6.5 bytes

```
/`\~_!:\@0@+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWa_QTYuriFa1iHAwctCFCUJkFN60MFYwUjBVMFEwVzBTMFSy4UPhcILYpUNzQUMHQWMEQyLBUMDJWMLJUMDaEGAEA)

```
/   Fold
`\~  split into two parts
_     input (row from STDIN as a list of integers)
!    zip
:     join
\      reverse
@       the second part
0      0
@     the first part
+     with addition
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 6 bytes

```
;ᶜç↔ᶻ+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FmutH26bc3j5o7YpD7ft1l5SnJRcDJVZcFMx2lDHSMdYx0THVMdMx1zHIpYLVSQWohIA)

```
;ᶜç↔ᶻ+
;       Nondeterministically split the input into two parts
 ᶜç     Optionally prepend a zero to the second part
   ↔    Reverse the second part
    ᶻ+  Zip with addition
```

The `+` operator is automatically vectorized, but it does not check if the two operands have the same length. So here I use `ᶻ` (`\zip`) to make sure that the two parts are of equal length.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 35 bytes

```
Set[f[a_,b___,c_],a+c,f@b]
f@a___=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z84tSQ6LToxXicpPj5eJzk@VidRO1knzSEplivNIREoZpv4P6AoM68kWlnXLs3BQTlWrS44OTGvrporKDEvPdXBXAfKsOCq/Q8A)

Input `[list...]`. Returns a sequence.

---

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 39 bytes

```
f@{a_,b___,c_}:={a+c,##&@@f@{b}}
f@a_=a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78/z/NoToxXicpPj5eJzm@1sq2OlE7WUdZWc3BASiTVFvLleaQGG@b@D@gKDOvJFpZ1y7NQTlWrS44OTGvrporKDEvPdXBXAfKsOCq/Q8A)

Input and output a list instead of a sequence.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-aE`, 36 bytes

```perl
map{$F[$_]+=pop@F}0..$#F/2-1;say"@F"
```

Takes advantage of the autosplit flag and iterates through the first half (rounded down) of the resulting list, modifying it in-place.

Slightly ungolfed:

```perl
for (0 .. ($#F / 2) - 1) {
    $F[$_] += pop(@F);
}
say "@F";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBaxS1aJT5W27Ygv8DBrdZAT09F2U3fSNfQujixUsnBTen/f0MjYy5DBSMFKKlgomCKYCmYcRkaKBgAuQYKhgb/8gtKMvPziv/rJiro@prqGRgaAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) `-E`, 60 bytes

```
s/^/</
:a
s/<(!*);(.*;)?(!*);$/\1\3,<\2/
ta
s/[<;]//g
s/,$//
```

Only works with zero and positive numbers.
Input is repeated exclamation marks separated by semicolons.
Output is repeated exclamation marks separated by commas.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1g/Tt9Gn8sqkatY30ZDUUvTWkNPy1rTHsxU0Y8xjDHWsYkx0ucqAamItrGO1ddPB7J0VPT1//9XtFYEITCGEFASRsFpRWsuIhT/yy8oyczPK/6v6woA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org/), 12 bytes

```
⬚0+⇌⊃↘↙⌊÷2⧻.
```

[Try it online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4qyaMCvih4ziioPihpjihpnijIrDtzLip7suCmYgWzEgMiAzIDQgNSA2IDcgOCA5XQpmIFsxIDIgMyA0IDUgNiA3IDhd)

```
⬚0+⇌⊃↘↙⌊÷2⧻.   input: a numeric vector
           ⌊÷2⧻     half of length, rounded down (let's call it k)
     ⊃↘↙     .   fork(drop, take): first k elements removed, first k elements
   ⇌               reverse the top
⬚0+                elementwise add, filling with zeros when lengths don't match
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 101 bytes

```python
lambda l:[sum(x)for x in zip(l[:len(l)//2],l[int(len(l)/2+.5):][::-1])]+[[],[l[len(l)//2]]][len(l)%2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3BCsIwEER/ZS9Clq6WplYl4Jese6hoMLBNQ1uh@vORSsGLx5l5vEmv6dHHOvvzJWvbXW8tqOPx2ZkZfT/ADCHCOySj7PQejWJZWiHlECezFrbYNeiEndtWglIwC7HyDxdZw8ZKXqxhsTJXBJagJtgTNAQHgiPBSQj@LSIuDd/XME7Gm4CI@QM)

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>18</s> <s>17</s> 13 bytes

```
V.Tc2Q aYsN;Y
```

My original approach was

```
WtQ aY+.)Q.(Q0;+Y
```

*-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder*

*-4 bytes thanks to FryAmTheEggman*

Comment: Try using `c2<list>` to split a list in half. Another command that might be useful is `.T`.

Comment: 17 bytes: [`WtQ aY+.)Q.(Q0;+Y`](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=WtQ+aY%2B.%29Q.%28Q0%3B%2BY&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, <s>75</s> 71 bytes

```
a=>a.slice(0,n=a.length/2).map(b=>b+a[--z],z=n*2).concat(n%1?a[n|0]:[])
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##dY7LDoIwEADvfMUeNLa6VPAdSfFDahMXRITglgh68PHtSLh7nUkmU9KTmvRe1K3P7px1F92Rjkk1VZFmIkDWpKqM8/Y6X0h1o1okOk5mZHz/ZfGledrj1HFKreBxeCDDn8DujZVd9KQ7FFw/WtBgPAATIiwQlggrhDXCBmGLsLP4x1nPRl7fblyVqcrlYogNEwQ6htPofREkvyepSlewmBx5ImXU/QA)

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions)*

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 70 bytes

```python
lambda l:[l[i]+l[~i]for i in range(len(l)//2)]+len(l)%2*[l[len(l)//2]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fpmCrEPM/JzE3KSVRIccqOic6M1Y7J7ouMzYtv0ghUyEzT6EoMS89VSMnNU8jR1Nf30gTKA9mqxppAZXDxWNj/xcUZeaVaKRpRBvqGOkY65jomOqY6ZjrWMRqanJhlwPK/AcA)

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>118</s> 111 bytes

```cs
a=>a.Reverse().Zip(a,(c,d)=>c+d).Take(a.Length/2).Concat(a.Skip(a.Length/2).Take(a.Length%2))
```

Byte count also includes

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVDfS8MwEH62f8UxkCYsVpy/HmoLQzYRJogTBMWHM71tYV06k2xsyP72mqzq7D2Ey3ffd/fdSXsiK0P1yio9hfHWOlokt1VZknSq0ja5I01GyTRqMUZKf6ZRpHFBdomSfvDoKwIfskRrob/PGySEdeiUhHWlCnhApRn/Kx1IIYYrLW@Udm/vAu4HerUggx8lBSjPYQJZjVmOyROtyVhiPHlVS4aCSVHwLJfdgifPOCeGyYj01M1Oe9yvpCU6D43ngfyv0qIe9ziv0@go2JgwL7JVSX4SFn7jMGq8LJVjsYgFxBD7P4VLsQ1kOXh/ySMGSxvu@1Z9Y3DL9ulIWefVw8oMUM4a@m/3F6Ocl0AXOtDhPG3dokVqPBwIu6h5d/WZ6IlzcSEuxRVcfwM)

As input please use numbers separated either with commas (`,`) or space.
Explanation:

```cs
a =>                                  // Take one input parameter (array)
a.Reverse()                           // Reverse it
.Zip(a, (c, d) => c + d)              // Take every corresponding member of reversed
                                      //    and original, and add them together
.Take(a.Length / 2)                   // Get first half of the collection
.Concat(                              // Add another collection
    a.Skip(a.Length / 2)              // Take input and leave out first half of it
    .Take(a.Length % 2)               // If length is odd, take first element (so the middle)
                                      //    otherwise create an empty collection
);
```

Comment: Can you save bytes by setting the length to a variable and switching to an explicit return?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder unfortunately it's longer

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>46</s> 43 bytes

```
f=(a,[b,...c]=a)=>c+c?[b+c.pop(),...f(c)]:a
```

```js
f=(a,[b,...c]=a)=>c+c?[b+c.pop(),...f(c)]:a

console.log(f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]).join(', ')) // 9, 9, 9, 9  ✓
console.log(f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]).join(', '))   // 8, 8, 8, 4  ✓
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important}
```

*Saved 3 bytes with inspiration from [Asaf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73012/asaf).*

Comment: Nice. You could change '1/c[0]' to '[]+c' to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @Asaf Actually I think `c+c` works for the third byte.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 9 bytes

```
`6L&)swtn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P8HMR02zuLwk7///aEMFIwVjBRMFUwUzBfNYAA)

#### How it works

Given an array `[a b c ... x y z]`, let `[a z]` be called the "crust" subarray and `[b c ... y z]` the "core" subarray.

The code consists in a loop that removes the crust, computes its sum, and moves the core to the top of the stack, ready for the next iteration. The loop condition is the number of elements in the core subarray

```
`       % Do...while
  6L    %   Push [2 -1+1j]. As an index, this is interpreted as 2:end-1
  &)    %   2-output reference indexing: pushes a subarray with the indexed 
        %   elements (core) and another with the ramaining elements (crust)
  s     %   Sum of (crust) subarray
  w     %   Swap. Moves the core subarray to the top
  t     %   Duplicate
  n     %   Number of elements.
        % End (implicit). Procced with next iteration if top of the stack is
        % nonzero; else exit
        % Display stack (implicit)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, <strike>42</strike> 38 chars

<strike>sub f{@a=map{$*+pop}splice@*,0,@*/2;@a,@*}</strike>

```
sub f{(map{$_+pop}splice@_,0,@_/2),@_}
```

Try for example like so:

```
perl -e 'my @input=(1..9); sub f{(map{$_+pop}splice@_,0,@_/2),@_}  print join(",",f(@input));
```

Comment: Fixed an error that crept in due to my emotional and professional attachment to variables. Refuse to be outgolfed by JS :P

Answer (score 1):

## [WendyScript](http://felixguo.me/wendy/), 72 bytes

```
<<f=>(l){<<r=[]<<b=l.size#i:0->b/2r+=l[i]+l[b-i-1]?b%2!=0r+=l[(b/2)]/>r}

f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]) // => [9,9,9,9]
f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]) // => [8,8,8,4]
```

[Try it online!](http://felixguo.me/#wendyScript)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 91 bytes

```
(s:Seq[Int])=>(s.take(s.size/2),s.reverse).zipped.map(_+_)++s.drop(s.size/2).take(s.size%2)
```

Answer (score 1):

### *Mathematica*, 52

```
(a=#;i=0;(i++;a[[i;;-i]]*=x)&/@a;(Tr@a+O@x^i)[[3]])&
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++17, <s>75</s> <s>73</s> 71 bytes

As unnamed lambda, accepting a container like `vector` or `list`, returns via modifying the input:

```cpp
[](auto&L){for(auto a=L.begin(),b=L.end();a<--b;L.pop_back())*a+++=*b;}
```

Using the well known 'goes-to' operator `<--` and the triple plus `+++`

Ungolfed and example:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

auto f=
[](auto&L){
 for(
  auto a=L.begin(),b=L.end();
  a<--b;
  L.pop_back()
 )
 *a+++=*b;
}
;

void test(auto L) {
 for(auto x:L)cout << x << ", ";
 cout << endl;
 f(L);
 for(auto x:L)cout << x << ", ";
 cout << endl << endl;
}

int main() { 
 vector<int> A = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, B = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
 test(A);
 test(B);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 93 bytes

Double digits! This is a lambda that takes an `int[]` and returns an `int[]`.

```java
l->{int n=l.length,i=0;for(;i<n/2;)l[i]+=l[n-++i];return java.util.Arrays.copyOf(l,n/2+n%2);}
```

### Ungolfed lambda

```java
l -> {
    int n = l.length, i = 0;
    for (; i < n / 2; )
        l[i] += l[n - ++i];
    return java.util.Arrays.copyOf(l, n / 2 + n % 2);
}
```

Quite straightforward. It folds the second half in place onto the first half of the input and returns a copy of just the first half.

Surprisingly, the array copy in the return statement seems to be the cheapest way to handle the final element quirk for odd-length inputs.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 67 bytes

```php
function($l){while($l)$o[]=array_shift($l)+array_pop($l);return$o;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/NCsIwEITP5inmELDiXvwXYvUkeBD0XoKUmpJKaUIaERGfvSbqTYSFnZlvYFmrbbfaWG3BS1Of0668NoWvTJPwevC46apWUXGTyTR3Lr@fWl2VPmbDj7fGRiec8lfXcCOenWDcq9a3SJGxXoYRYUyYEKaEGWFOWBCWkPQH/iGQTArGSuNUXugE3yN5GxQGDFCFNuhn6BMupmqSsMNEGAQk0jV@YPw6eXe@rRAed8fT9rAX3Qs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 28 bytes

```perl6
{.[^*/2]Z+.[$_-1...$_/2,$_]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1ovOk5L3yg2SlsvWiVe11BPT08lXt9IRyU@tvZ/cWKlQpqGjaGCkYKxgomCqYKZgrmChZ2mNRc2GTvN/wA)

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{                          }   # Anonymous code block
 .[^*/2]                       # The first half of the list
        Z+                     # Zip added to
          .[$_-1...$_/2        # The other half of the list
                       ,$_]    # And zero for the middle element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 21 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

-3 bytes thanks to @Adám.

```apl
(⌊2÷⍨≢)(↑{+⌿↑⍺⍵}∘⌽↓)⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X@NRT5fR4e2Pelc86lykqfGobWK19qOe/UD6Ue@uR71bax91zHjUs/dR22TNR12L/qc9apvwqLfvUd9UT/9HXc2H1huDVPZNDQ5yBpIhHp7B/9MUHvVutuACU@YA)

Explanation:

```apl
(⌊2÷⍨≢)(↑{+⌿↑⍺⍵}∘⌽↓)⊢  ⍝ Monadic function train
(⌊2÷⍨≢)                  ⍝ Left portion:
     ≢                   ⍝ Take the length of the input...
  2÷⍨                    ⍝ Divide it by two...
 ⌊                       ⍝ And floor it. This gives our midpoint index. Call it "X"
                      ⊢  ⍝ Right portion: return the original input. Call it "Y"
       (↑{+⌿↑⍺⍵}∘⌽↓)   ⍝ Midddle portion: takes X and Y as arguments
        ↑           ↓    ⍝ Take and drop Y by X. Essentially splits Y in half
                         ⍝ Presents the two halves to the next function
                 ∘⌽     ⍝ Reverse the second half
         {+⌿↑⍺⍵}       ⍝ Final function, takes first half and reversed second half
              ⍺⍵        ⍝ Construct a nested list of first and second halves...
             ↑          ⍝ ...and "mix" them into a matrix. Has the nice property that
                        ⍝ it will pad the first half with a zero if needed.
          +⌿           ⍝ Sum the matrix along the columns, return resulting vector
```

Comment: Dyalog Extended, 18 bytes: [`+⌿(⌊2÷⍨≢)(↑↑⍮⌽⍤↓)⊢`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/X/tRz36NRz1dRoe3P@pd8ahzkabGo7aJINS77lHP3ke9Sx61TdZ81LXof9qjtgmPevse9U319H/U1XxovTFIVd/U4CBnIBni4Rn8P03hUe9mCy4wZQ4A)

Comment: Training, 21 bytes: [`(⌊2÷⍨≢)(↑{+⌿↑⍺⍵}∘⌽↓)⊢`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X@NRT5fR4e2Pelc86lykqfGobWK19qOe/UD6Ue@uR71bax91zHjUs/dR22TNR12L/qc9apvwqLfvUd9UT/9HXc2H1huDVPZNDQ5yBpIhHp7B/9MUHvVutuACU@YA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")`

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 71 bytes

```cs
x=>{int i=0,l=x.Length;for(;i<l/2;)x[i]+=x[l-++i];return x[..(l-l/2)];}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYy9CsMgFEb3PkVGxRvbpr9wY8ZOHbqLk2gjiAVjqBDy7Nb2Abp8cDiHT0@tnly5zUH3LiSp4LeDFSWLYanQOLEDLzK/m/BMI9pXJOh6v@2QZukUE1n6ljGnMJo0x9BkyTnxbS2owrXg5hHrD7EkmLdUyx46OMARTnCGy0rpXw/Xb1E@)

-2 bytes thanks to @ceilingcat!

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 22 bytes

```
({.+/@,:|.@}.)~>.@-:@#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/Nar1tPUddKxq9Bxq9TTr7PQcdK0clP9rcqUmZ@QrWIChiYKulUKagqGCkYIxkGOqYKZgDpG3hEJMeQWL/wA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 34 bytes

```ruby
f=->l{l[1]?[l.shift+l.pop]+f[l]:l}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W1y6nOifaMNY@OkevOCMzrUQ7R68gvyBWOy06J9Yqp/Z/gUJadLShjpGOsY6JjqmOWWzsfwA)

Answer (score 1):

### Common Lisp, 106 bytes

```
(lambda(l)(setf(values a b)(floor(length l)2))`(,@(#1=subseq(mapcar'+ l(reverse l))0 a),@(#1#l a(+ a b))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5LDsIwDESvMgIhbJVKhP8GxFFwSwpILilJ6LJXLwEhPl55RtZ7LvUSmp7UuQaV84g2xLyUYHG5YkxkMMMcCyyxwprxn7F5NyZ15rsz4@hAiVdLRMSgE@Q7dNKNBj8GSl6pi6OQMgUbK2pF7zZAUDBV6SdPaq@neIbyjPlAkz0NzTbci2BvVEtTih9nUPK2tT4RlXkK4dfZUCGUvVhp@o/2GR4)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>102</s> 95 bytes

```java
i->{int l=i.length,o=l/2+l%2,r[]=new int[o];for(;o-->0;)r[o]=i[o]+(o<l+~o?i[l+~o]:0);return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZJLb4JAEIDv/oq5NIGIiPiWYtP05KGnHg2HFVZcu@6a3cXGGPrX6SCiWJ0EhgzfvGdLDqSzTb6LmBOt4ZMwAadWC1C6XYg3RKSUrDgFJgxVaxLT87@9YgdiGlZYoBtcBK3LCAzVBqzqm4l9ZuzgTORV@H224iwGbYhBdZAsgV2Z3foyiokUnYhKtV1Xc6lIU5Ptr4YFaMkzw6SA8Gq80anka5pALBNasM78hLUAD5nLqUjNxpEh7/pt/uI7ahmFgv6cC5dRsJbKCmSnM/cCW6EhZPhqW/KVt3/lG1uWKpp5dqCwGiVABXkRtO7bvwzgg2iqIWwMp5bTdOLAxHfAHzow7KH2cueRGiIxRmIydWA6Kj2eUn0HeiXpoS4fpPujZ@QIyUG/ijceINXLr1DeaAJnUC@v7mN268j@19DXURu6c2VmXDwNYbiwHlKXssVzc3Fh3H1Xihy1a2S1bqtepFvmsOpEtn0X5nJBjSvKW3nxBw)

-7 Thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

Comment: [`l-j-1` can be simplified to `l+~j`.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144481/52210) Also, you don't need the `j` if you loop in reverse order and reuse the `o`: [95 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/3c9t94r8).

Comment: There we go! Credited without alt-tabbing :PP

Comment: Suggest `l-l/2` instead of `l/2+l%2`

Answer (score 1):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 58 bytes

```
[reverse[:length/2],.[:length/2|floor]]|transpose|map(add)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/z@6KLUstag4NdoqJzUvvSRD3yhWRw/BqUnLyc8vio2tKSlKzCsuyC9OrclNLNBITEnRBOo11DHSMdYx0THVMdMxjwUA)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 65 bytes

```scala
l=>l take(l.size+1)/2 zipAll(l.reverse take l.size/2,0,0)map(_+_)
```

[Try it in Scastie!](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/dWXFqplHS76EWLI2xO8Gww)

Answer (score 1):

## k9, 12 bytes

```
+/++(;|)@'2^
```

Version 2021.09.20.

Cut in two, reverse second list, pad with zeroes, add.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 10 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 8.23 bytes

```
2APAur0Tz+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuharjBwDHEuLDEKqtCECUPEF66MNdYx0jHVMdEx1zHTMYyHCAA)

Sort-of port of [Adnan's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/136895/114446)

**Explanation:**

```python
2APAur0Tz+  # Implicit input
2AP         # Split in half
   Au       # Dump onto stack
     r      # Reverse top item
      0T    # Append a 0
        z+  # Zipped addition
```

Thunno's normal addition (`+`) will provide a nested list of each element of the first list plus each element of the second list.

Thunno's zipped addition (`z+`) zips the two lists together, discarding items if they are not of equal length.

So, we must append a 0 to the top list (since it will be the shorter one if the input contained an odd number of items) and then use zipped addition.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

There's gotta be a 9 here, somewhere.

```
òUÊ/2 oÔyx
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=8lXKLzIgb9R5eA&input=WzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDdd)

```
òUÊ/2 oÔyx     :Implicit input of array U
ò              :Partitions of length
 UÊ            :  Length of U
   /2          :  Divided by 2
      o        :Modify last element
       Ô       :  Reverse
        y      :Transpose
         x     :Reduce each by addition
```

### Also 10 bytes

```
íUÔoUÊz¹mx
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7VXUb1XKerlteA&input=WzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDddCi1R)

```
íUÔoUÊz¹mx     :Implicit input of array U
í              :Interleave with
 UÔ            :  Reverse U (mutates the original)
   o           :  Pop this many items (also mutates the original)
    UÊ         :    Length of U
      z        :    Floor divided by 2
       ¹       :End interleave
        m      :Map
         x     :  Reduce by addition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 41 bytes

```javascript
f=([b,...c])=>1/b?[b+~~c.pop(),...f(c)]:c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dczdCoIwFADge5/iXASe0Wlh/ySzB1kD53Kh2DbUvIl89UXdd/3B1@pJD6Zvwrhy/lbHaAXKijjnRjFRZOvqIqvlPBsefED2BYuGqbOJ@aR7aFx4jiBAJgAyI9gQbAl2BHuCA8GR4KToj6lE5YnxbvBdzTt/x1/GHzqgBlFAuXhZ1OxdMt76xmF6dSljefwA)

So many ways to reach 41

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 62 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.map((e,i)=>e+a[c=(b=a.length)-i-1]*(c!=i)).slice(0,++b/2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcoxEsIgEADA3l/Y3cmBgEYLh3wkk@KCJJJByJiM38fSKvXuzF9e/Scum8zlGeroKruW1ZsXgEARXRsEd97B4FilkKfthTJK05/AH11EVGuKPoAmIYazxepLXksKKpUJRugMWbrQlRq60b1HfBz2wx4bTVbvYfPn@gM)

Comment: Replace `-i-1` with `+~i` to save a byte.

Comment: And also `c!=i` with `c>i` for a byte.